# Where to import React-Bootstrap components from?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using React-Bootstrap version `1.0.0-beta.10`.

Whenever I want to use a component, for example `Alert`, I will get three import options from the IDE to choose from:

```
"react-bootstrap"
"react-bootstrap/Alert"
"react-bootstrap/es/Alert"
```

Which of them should I use and why?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** We have multiple options to import a component.

When importing directly from `react-bootstrap` you need to import as,

```
import {Alert} from `react-bootstrap`;
```

**Because `Alert` component is exported as `named export`.**

---

If you expand the `react-bootstrap` folder from `node_modules` folder, you will see multiple folders and files.

The files directly available in `react-bootstrap` folder are based on `ES5`.

When I say based on `ES5` means, the required package for this component are imported like this,

```
var _extends2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/extends"));
```

and you can import component as,

```
import Alert from `react-bootstrap/Alert`;
```

**Because `Alert` component is exported as `default export`.**

---

The files available in `es` folder are based on `ES6`.

When I say based on `ES6` means, the required package for this component are imported like this,

```
import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
```

and you can import component as,

```
import Alert from `react-bootstrap/es/Alert`;
```

**Because `Alert` component is exported as `default export`.**

Comment: I asked *which* of the sources I should use for import and *why*. You answered me *how* I can use them for import and explained the different methods of importing in JavaScript, including the difference between named and default export. Although your answer was thorough and well-formed, it did not answer the question. I am sorry for replying so late, but you missed the point. English is not my first language, but I thought I stated it clearly enough. Basically, I want to know whether I should do `import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert"` or `import {Alert} from "react-bootstrap"`. Difference?

Comment: @anddero, I did not point out which method you should use, because whichever method you choose is correct only. Using any method is not related to any performance decrease / increase. It is just available option's. My personal opinion is, using `import {Alert} from "react-bootstrap"`.

Comment: Using `import {Alert} from "react-bootstrap"` is also helpful, if we choose to use `CDN` over `npm` package.

Comment: That's where you are wrong, actually. I have researched this and found from React-Bootstrap docs, that importing from each component's own file, such as `import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert"` is more efficient in terms of how much code is sent to the client on loading the page. If you import from "react-bootstrap" you are effectively including the entire library, but if you import each component separately, you are only including those components. The only thing I do not know is why there is a "react-bootstrap/es/Alert" option. Which is why I came here to find out the truth.

Answer (score -1):

You must have to change your codebase.

react-bootstrap doesn't have a default export, so the default import syntax cannot be used in this case.

You can do the following though:

```
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
```

And then, you can use the Alert component.